# Prevent application from closing from Task Manager using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Prevent application from closing from Task Manager using VB.NET.

Comment: Google gave you an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083302/prevent-windows-application-vb-nettermination

Answer (score 1):

The only way to definitively prevent your application from being closed would be to run it under an account where the current user (using Task Manager) doesn't have rights to modify the application.

If it's running under your user's account, they will be able to kill it via Task Manager.

Otherwise, the only real option is to handle the `Closing` events on your forms, and request that they don't close.  That will prevent the normal "close application" from shutting down your application.